# How to cancel an AsyncTask and then to instantiate a new one with a single click?

Tags: android, button, new-operator, android-asynctask

I have a custom ***DownloadFiles*** class which extends ***AsyncTask***. The app launches itself and starts an ***AsyncTask*** in background for a default URL. On the UI, I have a number of buttons - each of them ***onClick*** event should cancel the current ***DownloadFiles*** instance and create new one with a different URL.

```
private OnClickListener categoryClick = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dft.cancel(true);
            int index = catigoriesHolder.indexOfChild(view);
            activeCategory.setText(categories[index]);
            dft = new DownloadFilesTask();
            dft.execute(rssFeedURL[index]);
            dft.execute(url);
        }
    };
```

**dft** is my ***DownloadFiles*** object, witch I need to cancel. And here is my ***onCancelled*** method:

```
protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }
```

I tried also to check inside the click-event if the **dft** is cancelled and then to create a new instance of my custom downloadable class. How could be this done and why when I trying this:

```
private OnClickListener categoryClick = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (dft.isCancelled()) {
                int index = catigoriesHolder.indexOfChild(view);
                activeCategory.setText(categories[index]);
                dft = new DownloadFilesTask();
                dft.execute(rssFeedURL[index]);
            } else {
                dft.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    };
```

it does not work, even on the second click?

I tried this after you advised me to check for ***isCancelled()*** inside the ***doInBackground(...)***

```
private OnClickListener categoryClick = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int index = catigoriesHolder.indexOfChild(view);
            activeCategory.setText(categories[index]);
            if (dft.isCancelled()) {
                dft.cancel(false);
                dft = new DownloadFilesTask();
                dft.execute(rssFeedURL[index]);
            } else {
                dft.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    };
```

But what happens, in this case:
- the default URL works fine, but when I click on a button, there is no action.

```
protected List<RSSItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            parse(urls[0]);

            if (feed == null) { return null; }

            rssList = feed.getAllItems();
            Iterator<RSSItem> iterator = rssList.iterator();

            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                if (isCancelled()) return null; 
                RSSItem rss = iterator.next();
                publishProgress(rss);
            }

            return rssList;
        }
```

After I checked the status of the current ***AsyncTask***, it works:

```
private OnClickListener categoryClick = new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String status = dft.getStatus().name();
            if (status.equals("FINISHED") || dft.isCancelled()) {
                dft = new DownloadFilesTask();
                int index = catigoriesHolder.indexOfChild(view);
                activeCategory.setText(categories[index]);
                dft.execute(rssFeedURL[index]);
            } else {
                dft.cancel(true);
            }
        }
    };
```

But still doesn't fit my expectations. Currently you should click twice to get new instance of ***DownloadFiles*** class. Could to transform it to a single click?

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me. Maybe more code would help us help you. Are you sure the OnClickListener is bound to the button?

Comment: But still does not work with a single click! You can see above the additional changes that I made to the source code.

Comment: ...and 'YES' I'm sure it is bound to the button, because at least onClick  it changes the name of current category!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .cancel(true) method only changes the internal canceled variable in the task. You have to call isCancelled() inside doInBackground() periodically and return when it evaluates true.

Also, please specify what is not working in each case.

Comment: After I moved `int index = catigoriesHolder.indexOfChild(view);
                activeCategory.setText(categories[index]);` into **IF** statement, my app works fine! Thanks for support!